# Why my custom domain doesn't work for blogger?

Tags: web, dns, hosting, blogger, google-search-console

I recently purchased a custom domain and I'm trying to set it up for my Blogger blog hosted on .blogspot.com. However, I'm encountering some issues with the setup and would appreciate any assistance in resolving them.

Here's what I've done so far:

DNS Settings: I added the necessary A records and two CNAME records as instructed by Blogger. I waited for over 48 hours to ensure that the DNS changes have propagated.

[CNAME and A records added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZDLT.png)

Google Search Console: Since Blogger was not confirming my domain even after 48 hours, I decided to add a TXT record provided by Google Search Console to verify ownership. After adding this record, Blogger finally accepted my custom domain.

[TXT record provided by Google Search Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBhp3.png)

Current Issue: However, the problem doesn't end here. Even after a few days, I'm facing two main issues:

[Blogger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoGSx.png)

Blogger is displaying a redirection page instead of my actual blog content.
My custom domain still doesn't seem to be working as intended.

[New Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vdct.png)

[Old Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlgqv.png)

I'm unsure what might be causing these ongoing issues. I've followed the setup instructions carefully, and all the necessary DNS records appear to be correctly configured. Despite this, I'm stuck with the redirection page and my custom domain not functioning as expected.

Could anyone provide some insights into what might be causing these problems? Is there a step I might have missed or an additional configuration I need to consider? Your guidance and expertise would be highly appreciated.